# Query for looking for unused columns in MS SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm working on a bad large database with a lot of unused fields and columns where every data is NULL. Is there any way to retrieve only the populated columns of a table with a query? I have no access to SQL Server Studio but via PHP

Comment: Ok I got to ask... why? What's going to be the next step when you find all of these columns?

Comment: I will be able to ignore them in every transaction I'll make with the new system

Comment: I can't help you with PHP but SSMS is a free download FYSA

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at `Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

From that, you can create some dynamic SQL to list table names and field names where all values are null

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>'
Select @SQL=@SQL+'Union All Select TableName=''['+Table_Schema+'].['+Table_Name+']'',FieldName='''+Column_Name+''' From ['+Table_Schema+'].['+Table_Name+'] having max(['+Column_Name+']) is null'+char(13)
  From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Set @SQL = Replace(@SQL,'>>>Union All','')
Exec(@SQL)
```

**I should add @scsimon has valid concerns/questions**

I didn't have a table where an entire column was null, so I created dbo.temp with 3 records and 3 fields.  Only field aaa was completely null.

The above dynamic sql returned

```
TableName       FieldName
[dbo].[temp]    aaa
```

One Line

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>';Select @SQL=@SQL+'Union All Select TableName=''['+Table_Schema+'].['+Table_Name+']'',FieldName='''+Column_Name+''' From ['+Table_Schema+'].['+Table_Name+'] having max(['+Column_Name+']) is null'+char(13) From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;Set @SQL = Replace(@SQL,'>>>Union All','');Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: Is that a query I can run in php?